# Java based Neural Network --- how to implement backpropagation

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation

I am building a test neural network and it is definitely not working. My main problem is backpropagation. From my research, I know that it is easy to use the sigmoid function. Therefore, I update each weight by (1-Output)(Output)(target-Output) but the problem with this is what if my Output is 1 but my target is not? If it is one at some point then the weight update will always be 0...For now I am just trying to get the darn thing to add the inputs from 2 input neurons, so the optimal weights should just be 1 as the output neuron simply adds its inputs. I'm sure I have messed this up in lots of places but here is my code:

```
    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Double[] inputs = {1.0, 2.0};
            ArrayList<Double> answers = new ArrayList<Double>();
            answers.add(3.0);

            net myNeuralNet = new net(2, 1, answers);

            for(int i=0; i<200; i++){

                myNeuralNet.setInputs(inputs);
                myNeuralNet.start();
                myNeuralNet.backpropagation();
                myNeuralNet.printOutput();
                System.out.println("*****");
                for(int j=0; j<myNeuralNet.getOutputs().size(); j++){
                    myNeuralNet.getOutputs().get(j).resetInput();
                    myNeuralNet.getOutputs().get(j).resetOutput();
                    myNeuralNet.getOutputs().get(j).resetNumCalled();
                }
            }
        }

    }


    package myneuralnet;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class net {

    private ArrayList<neuron> inputLayer;
    private ArrayList<neuron> outputLayer;
    private ArrayList<Double> answers;

    public net(Integer numInput, Integer numOut, ArrayList<Double> answers){
        inputLayer = new ArrayList<neuron>();
        outputLayer = new ArrayList<neuron>();
        this.answers = answers;

        for(int i=0; i<numOut; i++){
            outputLayer.add(new neuron(true));
        }

        for(int i=0; i<numInput; i++){
            ArrayList<Double> randomWeights = createRandomWeights(numInput);
            inputLayer.add(new neuron(outputLayer, randomWeights, -100.00, true));
        }

        for(int i=0; i<numOut; i++){
            outputLayer.get(i).setBackConn(inputLayer);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<neuron> getOutputs(){
        return outputLayer;
    }

    public void backpropagation(){
        for(int i=0; i<answers.size(); i++){
            neuron iOut = outputLayer.get(i);
            ArrayList<neuron> iOutBack = iOut.getBackConn();
            Double iSigDeriv = (1-iOut.getOutput())*iOut.getOutput();
            Double iError = (answers.get(i) - iOut.getOutput());

            System.out.println("Answer: "+answers.get(i) + " iOut: "+iOut.getOutput()+" Error: "+iError+" Sigmoid: "+iSigDeriv);

            for(int j=0; j<iOutBack.size(); j++){
                neuron jNeuron = iOutBack.get(j);
                Double ijWeight = jNeuron.getWeight(i);

                System.out.println("ijWeight: "+ijWeight);
                System.out.println("jNeuronOut: "+jNeuron.getOutput());

                jNeuron.setWeight(i, ijWeight+(iSigDeriv*iError*jNeuron.getOutput()));
            }
        }

        for(int i=0; i<inputLayer.size(); i++){
            inputLayer.get(i).resetInput();
            inputLayer.get(i).resetOutput();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Double> createRandomWeights(Integer size){
        ArrayList<Double> iWeight = new ArrayList<Double>();

        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            Double randNum = (2*Math.random())-1;
            iWeight.add(randNum);
        }

        return iWeight;
    }

    public void setInputs(Double[] is){
        for(int i=0; i<is.length; i++){
            inputLayer.get(i).setInput(is[i]);
        }
        for(int i=0; i<outputLayer.size(); i++){
            outputLayer.get(i).resetInput();
        }
    }

    public void start(){
        for(int i=0; i<inputLayer.size(); i++){
            inputLayer.get(i).fire();
        }
    }

    public void printOutput(){
        for(int i=0; i<outputLayer.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(outputLayer.get(i).getOutput().toString());
        }
    }

}

package myneuralnet;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class neuron {

    private ArrayList<neuron> connections;
    private ArrayList<neuron> backconns;
    private ArrayList<Double> weights;
    private Double threshold;
    private Double input;
    private Boolean isOutput = false;
    private Boolean isInput = false;
    private Double totalSignal;
    private Integer numCalled;
    private Double myOutput;

    public neuron(ArrayList<neuron> conns, ArrayList<Double> weights, Double threshold){
        this.connections = conns;
        this.weights = weights;
        this.threshold = threshold;
        this.totalSignal = 0.00;
        this.numCalled = 0;
        this.backconns = new ArrayList<neuron>();
        this.input = 0.00;
    }

    public neuron(ArrayList<neuron> conns, ArrayList<Double> weights, Double threshold, Boolean isin){
        this.connections = conns;
        this.weights = weights;
        this.threshold = threshold;
        this.totalSignal = 0.00;
        this.numCalled = 0;
        this.backconns = new ArrayList<neuron>();
        this.input = 0.00;
        this.isInput = isin;
    }

    public neuron(Boolean tf){
        this.connections = new ArrayList<neuron>();
        this.weights = new ArrayList<Double>();
        this.threshold = 0.00;
        this.totalSignal = 0.00;
        this.numCalled = 0;
        this.isOutput = tf;
        this.backconns = new ArrayList<neuron>();
        this.input = 0.00;
    }

    public void setInput(Double input){
        this.input = input;
    }

    public void setOut(Boolean tf){
        this.isOutput = tf;
    }

    public void resetNumCalled(){
        numCalled = 0;
    }

    public void setBackConn(ArrayList<neuron> backs){
        this.backconns = backs;
    }

    public Double getOutput(){
        return myOutput;
    }

    public Double getInput(){
        return totalSignal;
    }

    public Double getRealInput(){
        return input;
    }

    public ArrayList<Double> getWeights(){
        return weights;
    }

    public ArrayList<neuron> getBackConn(){
        return backconns;
    }

    public Double getWeight(Integer i){
        return weights.get(i);
    }

    public void setWeight(Integer i, Double d){
        weights.set(i, d);
    }

    public void setOutput(Double d){
        myOutput = d;
    }

    public void activation(Double myInput){
        numCalled++;
        totalSignal += myInput;

        if(numCalled==backconns.size() && isOutput){
            System.out.println("Total Sig: "+totalSignal);
            setInput(totalSignal);
            setOutput(totalSignal);
        }
    }

    public void activation(){
        Double activationValue = 1 / (1 + Math.exp(input));
        setInput(activationValue);
        fire();
    }

    public void fire(){
        for(int i=0; i<connections.size(); i++){
            Double iWeight = weights.get(i);
            neuron iConn = connections.get(i);
            myOutput = (1/(1+(Math.exp(-input))))*iWeight;
            iConn.activation(myOutput);
        }
    }

    public void resetInput(){
        input = 0.00;
        totalSignal = 0.00;
    }

    public void resetOutput(){
        myOutput = 0.00;
    }
}
```

OK so that is a lot of code so allow me to explain. The net is simple for now, just an input layer and an output layer --- I want to add a hidden layer later but I'm taking baby steps for now. Each layer is an arraylist of neurons. Input neurons are loaded with inputs, a 1 and a 2 in this example. These neurons fire, which calculates the sigmoid of the inputs and outputs that to the output neurons, which adds them and stores the value. Then the net backpropagates by taking the (answer-output)*(output)*(1-output)(output of the specific input neuron) and updates the weights accordingly. A lot of times, it cycles through and I get infinity, which seems to correlate with negative weights or sigmoid. When that doesn't happen it converges to 1 and since (1-output of 1) is 0, my weights stop updating.

The numCalled and totalSignal values are just so the algorithm waits for all neuron inputs before continuing. I know I'm doing this an odd way, but the neuron class has an arraylist of neurons called connections to hold the neurons that it is forward connected to. Another arraylist called backconns holds the backward connections. I should be updating the correct weights as well since I am getting all back connections between neurons i and j but of all neurons j (the layer above i) I am only pulling weight i. I apologize for the messiness --- I've been trying lots of things for hours upon hours now and still cannot figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You might find this article helpful: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30596, last page lists full source code.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the best textbooks on neural networks in general are Chris Bishop's and Simon Haykin's. Try reading through the chapter on backprop and understand why the terms in the weight update rule are the way they are.The reason why I am asking you to do that is that backprop is more subtle than it seems at first. Things change a bit if you use a linear activation function for the output layer (think about why you might want to do that. Hint: post-processing), or if you add a hidden layer. It got clearer for me when I actually read the book.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to compare your code to this single layer perceptron.

I think you have a bug in your backprop algo. Also, try replacing the sigmoid with a squarewave.

http://web.archive.org/web/20101228185321/http://en.literateprograms.org/Perceptron_%28Java%29

Answer (score 0):

> what if my Output is 1 but my target is not?

The sigmoid function 1/(1 + Math.exp(-x)) never equates to 1. The lim as x approaches infinity is equal to 0, but this is a horizontal asymptote, so the function never actually touches 1. Therefore, if this expression is used to compute all of your output values, then your output will never be 1. So (1 - output) shouldn't ever equal 0.

I think your issue is during the calculation of the output. For a neural network, the output for each neuron is typically sigmoid(dot product of inputs and weights). In other words, value = input1 * weight1 + input2 * weight2 + ... (for each weight of neuron) + biasWeight. Then that neuron's output = 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-value). If it's calculated in this way, the output won't ever be equal to 1.